# Implicit Differentiation where y is a function of x

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am learning about implicit differentiation. The author gave 2 examples of differentiation as shown below:

Example 1: $$\frac{d}{dx}[x^3]=3x^2$$

Example 2: $$\frac{d}{dx}[y^3]=3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}$$

The explanation for adding$$\frac{dy}{dx}$$ since y is a function of x.

But where is the "y" in this equation? The only y I see is $$y^3$$

Comment: Use the product rule $$y^{3} = y \cdot y \cdot y \implies \frac{d}{dx} y^{3} = \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot y^2+ y \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot y + y^2 \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = 3y^{2} \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, $$\frac{d(y^3)}{dx}=\frac{d(y^3)}{\color{blue}{dy}}\frac{\color{blue}{dy}}{dx}=3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Example: A circle $x^2+y^2=9$. If you want $\frac{dy}{dx}$, you'll have to write $y$ as subject of the equation. But with implicit differentiation: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2+y^2\right)=\frac{d}{dx}(9)$$ and $$2x+\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)=0=2x+\frac{d}{dy}(y^2)\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Comment: The phrase "Implicit Differentiation" contains the word **Implicit**. It means *there are some functions defined* with an **implicit relation** (often in the form $F(x,y)=0$). You can't see this relation directly(kind of). In my example, $y=f(x)$ or if you wish $x=g(y)$. The two variables are implicitly related.

Comment: in this case, the y is a function of x refers to isnt  $$f(x) = y^3$$?

Comment: You're correct.